# Logout PFuser brings you back to login screen, but navigationController is now blank?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I'm using parse.com. I have a `UINavigationController` of custom class `chwRootViewController` and it is set to the initial view.

When a user successfully logs in this is run:

```
// Sent to the delegate when a PFUser is logged in.
- (void)logInViewController:(PFLogInViewController *)logInController didLogInUser:(PFUser *)user {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Now `chwMainviewController` is the `UIViewController` that is shown when the login method dismisses `chwRootViewController`. In the main view controller I have an `IBAction` for clicking the logout button that is like this:

```
- (IBAction)logoutButtonClicked:(id)sender {

    [PFUser logOut]; // Log out


    // Return to login page
    if (![PFUser currentUser]) {

        [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
```

The problem is the last line returns the user to the login screen, but now `chwMainViewController` is no longer ready and waiting behind the login screen. When you login the second time there is just a black screen when the `chwRootViewController` is dismissed. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You may use the following steps:

In your initial `view controller` i.e. `chwMainviewController.m` file, Do:

1. Implement the `viewDidAppear` method as shown:

   ```
   - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
   {
       [super viewDidAppear:YES];
       if (![PFUser currentUser]) {
           [self showLogInPage];
       }
   }
   ```
2. Write the `code` to display the **Parse Login Page** in the `showLogInPage` method as shown below:

   ```
   - (void)showLogInPage
   {
       PFLogInViewController *logInController = [[PFLogInViewController alloc] init];
       logInController.delegate = self;
       logInController.fields = PFLogInFieldsUsernameAndPassword | PFLogInFieldsLogInButton | PFLogInFieldsSignUpButton | PFLogInFieldsFacebook;
       PFSignUpViewController *signUpController = [[PFSignUpViewController alloc] init];
       signUpController.delegate = self;
       logInController.signUpController = signUpController;
      [self presentViewController:logInController animated:YES completion:nil];
   }
   ```
3. Finally, implement your `logoutButtonClicked` as follows:

   ```
   - (IBAction)logoutButtonClicked:(id)sender {
       [PFUser logOut];
       [self showLogInPage];
   }
   ```

**Note:**

If you are not using ***storyboard***, then make sure that you set `chwMainviewController` as your `rootViewController` in your `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method.

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are dismissing the `rootViewController`.

I think you should go with a structure like

in your `didFinishLaunching` you have a `RootCOntroller` like `navigationController`->`rootViewController`

and for login check the value at `applicationDidBecomeActive` and present a controller as model with help of `navigationController`